# Can I recover source code from app on test iPhone --Swift/Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone

I have spent the last 4 days coding 20 hours a day to make my first self guided project ever for iOS. I had a working prototype and decided to tackle the layout for landscape mode. Long story short, in my fiddling I made mistakes that ruined portrait mode and so I (being a complete novice in Xcode and to programming) accidentally **clicked discard all changes** thinking it would reset me to my last save. It ended up wiping my whole file and dumping some of the old contents into the trash.

I could only find half my project in the trash so I was hoping I could recover the code from my test iPhone that has an older version of the program saved on it and just start again from there (with backups this time).

My iPhone is a physical version (not the Simulator)

[image: The Button I Pressed]

Comment: there was never any line of your code on the phone. only the compiled app.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I feared, do you know of any other way of recovering the data?

Comment: I don't even have the foggiest idea where you hit this discard button, but if you didn't save backups or committed into a revision control system, only one option is left: rewrite it from what is in your head.

Comment: Do you use Apple's Time Machine backup utility on your system?

Comment: Turn on snapshots in Xcode and use Time Machine on your Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is likely that you are out of luck here. Normally you would commit the changes and then, if you don't want them, you can revert back (and forward) as you wish. If you had commited (or stashed/staged) then you would be ok.

**But...**

There is a *small* possibility that Finder can help you though. Read [this answer](https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim.git) and see if that helps.

Basically, quit Xcode, open the file that you were working in using TextEdit, go to File > Revert To > Browse All Versions and see if you can restore one that you previously used. Do this for each file and then reopen Xcode and keep your fingers crossed and pray to the code gods!

Comment: You just saved countless hours of work from going down the drain!

Comment: Cool, I'd rather be wrong and have you recover some stuff! - I don't see what this has to do with Xvim, though.

Comment: @AN No problem my friend. Remember, don't be a fool, stay in school, cover your tool, and commit your code. ;) hehe

Comment: Haha. Thank You again, you saved me from a mental breakdown

Answer (score 2):

When you said Discard All Changes, you were warned that this would discard all changes. If you went ahead and did it anyway, you have only yourself to blame: you were warned! You are now back your previous commit. Nothing after that is recoverable.

The correct procedure would have been, not to discard your changes, but to commit them! Now the current state of things would have been saved, and you could then proceed to work your way backwards to a working state of things in a recoverable and systematic manner.

By the way, this is not an Xcode matter or a programming matter; it's a version control matter. It's very good that you are using `git`, but perhaps you should pause and read up on it before you continue using it.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know what other site to go to. You've confirmed my fears. And your right, I screwed up :)

Comment: I will make your answer the answer in a sec, I just have to wait 6 minutes

Comment: Sorry about the unhappy answer, but you learned a valuable lesson: commit _everything_! Commit early and often. You have a wonderful ability, so use it.

Comment: Do you know where the files go when changes are discarded? Are they overwritten?

Comment: They don't "go" anywhere. If you added files and then discarded all changes without committing, those files are removed, not trashed.